# Conditionally null values inside of a list of SqlParameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

We have a block of code that creates a list of sqlParameters and then passes them to the stored procedure.  A requirement came in to conditionally null a few of the values based on whether or not the input textbox is blank.

Base code:

```
var SqlParams = new List<SqlParameter> {
    new SqlParameter("@SomeFloat", SqlDbType.FLoat) {Value = f},
    ....
}
```

I tried a few variations on something, but it didn't work and VS gives an error about no implicit conversion between float and null.

```
new SqlParameter("@SomeFloat", SqlDbType.Float) {Value = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text) ? double.Parse(tb.Text) : DBNull.Value)},
```

Is there a way to do this maintaining the list of parameters so that we dont have to rewrite the whole module?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using DeriveParameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, you just have to make sure the conditional operator knows what its result should be. Cast one of the `double.Parse` or `DBNull.Value` to `object`

I've also removed some brackets and swapped the condition to make it easier to remove.

```
new SqlParameter("@SomeFloat", SqlDbType.Float) 
    {
        Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text) 
            ? DBNull.Value
            : (object)double.Parse(tb.Text)
    }
```

However I would normally do something like this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeFloat", double.Parse(tb.Text));
```

And not specify the value if the textbox is blank and let the stored procedure handle that case.

Comment: This is perfect - thanks!  And I'd love to rewrite this, but there are a quite a few parameters and only four of them need this condition, so I was looking for the more straightforward way to knock out this change without impacting the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would totally recommend to point each call to a method and let it decide the value that's going to be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for an extension:

```
    public static object TryParseSqlValue(this object input)
    {
        if (null == input)
            return DBNull.Value;
        if (input.GetType() == typeof(string) && input.ToString() == string.Empty)
            return DBNull.Value;
        else
            return input;
    }

myTextBox.Text.TryParseSqlValue();  // returns either the non-empty 
                                    // string or DBNull.Value
```

You can modify it for other datatypes...